# locations are received before locationRequest.setFastestInterval

Tags: android, location, location-client

I have set the Interval and Fastest Interval as,

```
locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 60 * 1000); //30 minutes
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(30 *60 * 1000); //30 minutes
```

But I sometimes receive the location updates before 30 minutes and the interval is uneven. e.g., sometime the location update is received after 3 minutes, 4 minutes, 10 minutes.

My Pending intent is set as,

```
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, mIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Is this a expected behaviour or I need to handle it some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Lowering the `setFastestInterval` rate will most likely result in more stable location updates.

Also Check out this video for more info:
https://youtu.be/81W61JA6YHw